# When clicking a facebook like button on rails 3 would also like to call a method

Tags: iframe, ruby-on-rails-3.1, facebook-like

I am implementing a facebook like button on my rails 3.1 app but would like to keep track of the amount of facebook likes. This is helpful for me as it will allow me to sort my images by the most facebook likes. I am using the simpler way of iframe and facebook like plugin. My code for my helper is

```
def facebook_like
        content_tag :iframe, nil, :src => "http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=#{CGI::escape(request.url)}&layout=standard&show_faces=true&width=450&action=like&font=arial&colorscheme=light&height=80", :scrolling => 'no', :frameborder => '0', :allowtransparency => true, :id => :facebook_like
end
```

For my model, I have a personalize like attribute. What would be the best way to increase the like attribute whenever someone click on the facebook like.

I also know that facebook has a graph.facebook.com that will tell me how many shares there are for that object. Will that be relevant in updating my own internal like?

Comment: you could bind a javascript click listener to the "like" button and call your application with data, but i don't know if that's possible within the iframe. i think this violates the cross domain policy.

Comment: that's what I think too... I am now thinking of updating the model's internal likes with graph.facebook.com everytime the model is viewed. However, that would make it slightly inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a handler to an event that invokes your callback when a particular event is fired up in Facebook **Like**.
The syntax for attaching handler should look like this:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('**edge.create**', function (**response**) {
  //write your call back functionality here
};
```

**Note**: The **response** parameter to the callback function contains the URL that was liked.
For more information you can read API documentation here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/